# How to change/specify BaseStyle size on $x$ and $y$ axes?

Tags: plotting, style, fonts, size

In the given code, how can I have different `BaseStyle` sizes on $x$ and $y$ axes?

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 20}, Frame -> True, PlotRange-> {0,9},
 FrameTicks -> {{{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, None}, {Automatic, None}},BaseStyle-> 8]
```

> More specifically, I want that the `BaseStyle` on the $x$ axis is larger than on the $y$ axis; and also that on the $y$ axis, the first and the last numbers i.e. $0,9$ are larger than those in between them (something like the given picture).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the overall style of the ticks with `FrameTicksStyle` and specify individual tick styles in `FrameTicks`

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 20}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 9}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{0, Style[0, 16]}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
     8, {9, Style[9, 16]}}, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {8, 16},
 FrameLabel -> {{"X", None}, {"Y", None}}]
```

[image]